# validation multiple select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to validate a form with many select list inputs, but is not working, i want to check if the user selected any of it, and if not show a error message. But is not working.

```
 if(input_select.length > 0){
            for(var i=0; i< input_select.length; i++){
                if (input_select[i]+':selected'){
                    temp = temp+1;
                }
            }



            if(temp === 0){
                isValid = false;
                $('.error-list').append("<li class='error'><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>Required select list fields</li>");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try https://jqueryvalidation.org/?

Comment: have a running code with error ?  fidler, jsfidle anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code that should help.

**HTML**

```
<select id="my-select-box">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<ul id="error-list"></ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var selectObject = document.getElementById('my-select-box');
if (selectObject.options.selectedIndex == 0) {
    isValid = false;
    $('#error-list').append("<li class='error'><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>Required select list fields</li>");
}
```